# Execute Postgres Function in VBNet

Tags: vb.net, postgresql

I want to execute my postgres  function having date as parameeter in VBNet and show the result in datagridview.Below is my code Please tell me where i am getting wrong.I think i am writing wrong command to execute function.I know this might be wrong way but i am using first time postgres function in VBNet

```css
Imports Npgsql
Public Class Form1
    Dim connstring As String = String.Format("Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;" +
  "Username=xxxx;Password=xxxx;Database=EMS_Demo_db;")
    Dim conn As NpgsqlConnection = New NpgsqlConnection(connstring)
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try
            conn.Open()
            Dim Command As NpgsqlCommand = New NpgsqlCommand("SELECT * FROM lastsevendays_sp ' + DateTimePicker1.Value + '", conn)
            Dim reader As NpgsqlDataReader = Command.ExecuteReader()
            Dim data_Table1 As New DataTable
            data_Table1.Load(reader)
            DataGridView1.DataSource = data_Table1
            reader.Close()
            conn.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: `lastsevendays_sp` is a stored procedure right?

Comment: Yes It is a stored procedure

Comment: And what is the name of the date parameter?

Comment: userdate with datatype as date

Comment: Okay. Can you edit your question to include the error message you receive? And please post the *exact* message. I see a few flaws in your code, but for all I know this could be yet another *"I cannot connect to my database"* question.

Comment: You can't call a stored procedure using SELECT..  You should search "how to call a stored procedure from VB.net".

Comment: Sir can you give a link for reference or can you say how can i call postgres function having parameter in it

Comment: @Steve: Postgres has only functions .. so any stored code is called via SELECT

Comment: @Parth a side note : you should format date time(yyyy-MM-dd format) so that your select query in vb.net code should look like `SELECT * FROM lastsevendays_sp (' + format( DateTimePicker1.Value ,"yyyy-MM-dd")+ ')`

Comment: I have used like this...  Dim Command As NpgsqlCommand = New NpgsqlCommand("SELECT * FROM lastsevendays_sp ('" + DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "')", conn)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You miss a parenthesis - The parenthesis are mandatory in PostgreSQL SQL:

Should be:

```
Dim Command As NpgsqlCommand = New NpgsqlCommand("SELECT * FROM lastsevendays_sp( ' + DateTimePicker1.Value + ')", conn)
```

I am not a .NET expert, so I don't know a true solution, but there are two risks:

- SQL injection - DateTimePicker1.Value is not sanitized!!!
- Unexpected format - Postgres understands to ANSI format well (YYYY-MM-DD)